# How to make multiple image source assignments not make the page stuck?

Tags: javascript, html, image, asynchronous, html-lists

I need to dynamically create a list of a couple thousand elements. Each list item contains an image of about half a Kb and some text.

The problem is that the assignment of all image sources to my list items, using the `.src` of my `<img>` elements, is taking a long time and making the page completely stuck for some seconds.

Is there a way that I could do this maybe asynchronously or more efficiently so that the page doesn't get stuck during the list generation?

Here's a simplified version of my code. If I remove the line with `.src` assignment, the code runs instantaneously.

```
// About a couple thousand elements
const item_data = [ 
    {text: "text1", image: "img/image1.png"}, 
    {text: "text2", image: "img/image2.png"},
    ... ];

const my_list = document.createElement("ul");

for (const item of item_data) {

    const list_item = document.createElement("li");

    const list_item_text = document.createElement("p");
    list_item_text.innerText = item.text;

    const list_item_image = document.createElement("img");
    list_item_image.src = item.image;

    list_item.appendChild(list_item_text);
    list_item.appendChild(list_item_image);

    my_list.appendChild(list_item);
}

document.body.appendChild(my_list);
```

Comment: You should implement a lazy-loading mechanism, to load images only when required (when visible to user) instead of all at once.

Comment: @Sedenion Is there a recommended approach to implement the lazy-loading mechanism?

Comment: I never tested, but with modern browser, you can use the `loading` attribute as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading . Otherwise, you have to implement your own mechanism, you may find several examples simply by searching "lazy loading"

Comment: @Sedenion The `loading` attribute worked brilliantly.

This was the line I added: `list_item_image.setAttribute("loading", "lazy");`, and it has to come before the `.src` assignment, otherwise it appears to have no effect.